# Printer reinstalls as new printer again, and again

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, hp-laserjet

Have a HP Laserjet 6P connected through USB to my IBM T500 Laptop, Win XP.

If I disconnect the printer, shut laptop, start laptop and reconnect printer, the printer reinstalls - this time as HP Laserjet 6P (1). Next time it will install as HP Laserjet 6P (2), the other two installs still present. Any ideas?
Thanks, Bo

Comment: what is IMB T63?

Comment: oops, IBM T63 :)

Comment: I even don't know IBM ever released T63, that's why I was asking, I thought IBM changed to T400/T500 after T61?

Comment: Right, it's actually a T500. To my defence this is my fathers.. How about taking a crack at this VERY annoying printer problem :)

Comment: Sorry about the irrelevant questions above, regarding your problem, check this post: http://www.pchelpforum.com/printing/56388-h-p-printer-keeps-reinstalling.html#post345771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I found out: 
The T500 has 3 USB ports. If you disconnect the the printer you must use the same USB port when reconnecting. Otherwise it will reinstall as per the question above.